# method in class cannot be applied to given type

Tags: java, methods

I am trying to create a method that takes 50% of the difference in balance between the receiver class and the argument class and gives it to the argument class.

So far I have:

```
private boolean lastReceived;    
private boolean lastGiven;    
public Account account;


/**
* Constructor for objects of class MoneyFrog
*/
public MoneyFrog(String holderName, String accountNumber, double anAmount)
{
    super();
    this.lastReceived = false;
    this.lastGiven = false;
    this.account = new Account();
    this.account.setHolder(holderName);
    this.account.setNumber(accountNumber);
    this.account.setBalance(anAmount);
    super.setColour(OUColour.GREEN);
} 

/**
 * Getter method for the Account variable account
 */
public Account getAccount(Account account)
{
    return this.account;
}

/**
 * Method to transfer the 50% of the difference between the balance of the 
 * receiver MoneyFrog and the argument MoneyFrog to the argument MoneyFrog.
 */
public void transfer(MoneyFrog moneyFrog)
{
 this.getAccount().transfer(moneyFrog.getAccount(),this.getAccount().getBalance()/2);
}
```

but the code **.getAccount**() is throwing up the error 
"method getAccount in class MoneyFrog cannot be applied to given types; required:Account; 
found:no arguments; 
reason:actual and formal argument lists differ in length"

Can someone advise me as to why the method getAccount cant be applied here? or what other way I should be going about this?

Comment: getters don't carry parameters - setters do.

Comment: Your `getAccount()` method takes an (unused) `Account` parameter and you're trying to call it without supplying one. (Pretty basic stuff, really.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at the method signature:

```
public Account getAccount(Account account)
                             ↑
```

It *expects* an object of type `Account`, you cannot write:

```
this.getAccount()
```

with no arguments. According to your class, I think you don't need to pass `Account` object to the method, so removing it from the method definition should solve your problem.

I highly recommend you to visit [The Java™ Tutorials - Defining Methods](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methods.html) to better know the basic concepts of Java.

Comment: Specifically, I think the OP intended for it to take no arguments. So should change the method signature, not the caller.

Answer (score -1):

```
   /**
    * Getter method for the Account *field* account
    */
   public Account getAccount()
   {
     return this.account;
    }
```